# Firebase Flutter serve page based on login

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I have 2 types of user and based on user details from firestore, I want to serve the type of homepage. In this code, as soon as the user logs in, the listener here prints out the user ID based on the user that just logged in.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder<User?>(
        stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if(snapshot.hasData){
            print('reached here'); 
            User user = snapshot.data!;
            final authUser = MyUser.getUser(user.uid);
            print(authUser); 
            return StudentHomeScreen();
          }
          else{
            return LoginScreen();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

From here, how can I query the user details based on the User ID. I cannot place async await here and query the user details to return different home screens. Please help me solve this.

Comment: What about `FutureBuilder` to get the async data and build accordingly?

Comment: I am really new. Could you please add the code to do so? I don't know how.

Comment: Check [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html). Basically `MyUser.getUser(user.uid)` is a future, you add it in the `future` property and then manage the result, see the link.

Comment: How can I place FutureBuilder here because inside of snapshot.hasData, I don't have a child property. And my MyUser.getUser(user.uid) depends upon the result of the StreamBuilder.

Comment: `return FutureBuilder...` instead of `return StudentHomeScreen();`